# Python call a function by indirection

Tags: python, lambda

Windows7, Python2.7 MPD2.

I am writing a program to control MPD.

MPD has several (over 50) different functions.

Normally one would make a call in the form:

```
mpd_client.pause()
#or
mpd_client.playlistmove(playlist_name, old_pos, new_pos)
```

I want to encapsulate all the separate calls in one function so I can use a single try / except.

I am thinking I want to use some sort of lambda, and *args but I have little experience with either of those.

In the body of my program, I want to call something like this:

```
MPD('pause')
#or
MPD('playlistmove', playlist_name, old_pos, new_pos)
```

I envision my function looking something like...

```
def MPD(required_param, *args):
    try:
        mpd_client.required_param(args)
    except:
        ...
```

of course, this isn't working.

Short of writing a huge switch statement and 50 different try structures, is there a way I can use lambda?

maybe something like:

```
lambda m=mpd_client.required_param: m(args)
```

but, this isn't working either.

I don't know.

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `getattr()` to retrieve the actual method to call by name:

```
getattr(mpd_client, required_param)(*args)
```

(Note that you also need the `*` in front of the `args` for the function call as well, to re-expand the argument list back into separate arguments.)

Comment: Thanks Amber, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is object.__dict__, as in your code:

```
func = mpd_client.__dict__['pause']
func()
func = mpd_client.__dict__['playlistmove']
func(playlist_name, old_pos, new_pos)
```